# CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile creates a new window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, mfc, mdi

Recently we moved our C++ project, which uses MFC, from VS2008 to VS2010.

And there is a small issue: in our MDI interface, after we call a function CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile, the app not only opens the file, but also creates a new empty MDI window.

If we change the toolset (Project properties -> General -> Platform toolset) back to v90 (VS2008), we do not experience this problem.

Maybe someone saw the same issue and knows, what we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. maybe the explanation will help someone:

The problem was in MFC function:

```
CDocument* CDocManager::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName)
```

in VS2008 it called a function

```
return pBestTemplate->OpenDocumentFile(szPath);
```

in VS2010 it calls another function (with different number of parameters)

```
return pBestTemplate->OpenDocumentFile(szPath, bAddToMRU, TRUE);
```

which we didn't override in our own implementation of CMultiDocTemplate

Comment: A useful MSDN page describing breaking changes in newer versions of Visual Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

effectively there is a change in the file docmgr.cpp which calls the opendocumentfile function.

if you derived a class from CMultiDocTemplate watch out for this changes.

In fact your post helped me to find an error in my application.