# CWinApp OpenDocumentFile "unsupported operation" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, ms-office

### Problem

I'm trying to open an MFC program that reads a Microsoft Access database (.mdb) and allows the user to view or modify the data. This is an existing program (and source code) given to me by a group in another lab where the program opens and works just fine.

In our lab, I have yet to see it load properly. When run, it pops up a dialog box that says, "**Attempted an unsupported operation**". Windows then offers me a chance to debug and such before it crashes.

### Environment

In the other lab, they use Windows 7 and Microsoft Office 2010, and it works.

In our lab, I've tried Windows 7 with Office 2013 and Windows XP with Office 2010. The latter crashes without giving me the dialog box. I don't know if we have a Win7/MSO2010 machine.

### The Function

I have the source code for the program. The solution file implies it was last developed in VS2010, which the computers I tested on had installed as well. Running it out of Visual Studio 2010 or straight from the executable yields the same results.

I have added additional debug dialog boxes to the code that narrow down the problem to [this function call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sh7b8das(v=vs.100).aspx), which the code never gets past:

```
CwinApp:OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
```

The single string passed into the function is a path and filename for the MS Access database to be opened. It exists in a temporary directory created by another program. This is on a drive other than C, though I've tested some there, as well. Problems with programs related to this one often stem from files with "read only" status, but I continually check the temporary files created, and they are write-able.

### Documentation

I found [this information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.100).aspx) titled "Breaking Changes in Visual C++" for VS2010 through another SO question:

> A new virtual function was added to the CDocTemplate class. This new virtual function is CDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile. The previous version of OpenDocumentFile had two parameters. The new version has three parameters. To support the restart manager, any class derived from CDocTemplate must implement the version that has three parameters. For more information about the function, see CDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile. The new parameter is bAddToMRU.

### Code

I feel this might be the answer! But I don't have a strong idea of exactly what to change to get this to work. Here's where I stopped:

Program.cpp

```
CDocument* ProgramApp::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName, BOOL bAddToLRU, BOOL bMakeVisible)
{
    // Add specialized code here and/or call base class

    // Debug messages added
    CDocument* tempDoc;
    AfxMessageBox(lpszFileName);

    tempDoc = CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile(lpszFileName, bAddToMRU);

    AfxMessageBox("Opened database!");

    return tempDoc;
}
```

Program.h

```
class ProgramApp : public CWinApp
{
public:

...

    virtual CDocument* OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName, BOOL bAddToMRU, BOOL bMakeVisible);
```

afxwin.h

```
class CWinApp : public CWinThread
{

...

virtual CDocument* OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName);
virtual CDocument* OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName, BOOL bAddToMRU);
```

Changing the Program.cpp call to be from a "Template" class caused errors, but I wouldn't be surprised if that's towards the answer. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363383/cwinappopendocumentfile-creates-a-new-window) looks similar, but I'm not sure exactly what to do.

My hope is that this problem has a simple solution that someone more knowledgeable can give me. I would be much appreciative, and additional context would help a lot.

### Edit: Debugging

I drilled down into the Windows code to see what was precisely going wrong. It seemed too dense to understand, but a coworker and I may have clues based on it. The failure message happens here:

dlgdata.cpp

```
// Could be a windowless OCX
pSite = m_pDlgWnd->GetOldControlSite(nIDC);
if (pSite == NULL)
{
    TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Error: no data exchange control with ID 0x%04x.\n", nIDC);
    ASSERT(FALSE);
    AfxThrowNotSupportedException();
}
```

...Although we are seeing debugger issues here:

occcont.cpp

```
COleControlSiteOrWnd *pemp = new COleControlSiteOrWnd(hwndCtrl, pOccDlgInfo->m_pItemInfo[i].bAutoRadioButton);
ASSERT(IsWindow(pTemp->m_hWnd));
if (IsWindow(pTemp->m_hWnd))
{
    hwndStart = pTemp->m_hWnd;
    ...
```

My coworker believes this could have little to do with the opening of this document as I suspected and more to do with objects/controls we don't have on our lab computers trying to be used for the program.

Comment: Debug. What happens if you run the program in the debugger?
As far that I can see this note about the doc template only applies to you when you want to use the restart manager. The version with to parameter exists and calls the one with 3 (second parameter set o TRUE). Or do you have your own template.
Just debug and step into the code until the crash happens.

Comment: Edited with code locations where error is actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem in opendocumentfile(), there was a control in CFormView class which i was not using so i commented it out but forget to delete from .rc file. Once i remove the control entry from .rc file the problem disappear.

there should be no control variable uninitialize , please check that also